# Has anybody real world experience with buckminster?

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process, build-automation, buckminster

I'm currently evaluating ivy, maven and buckminster to ease our build process. Conceptually buckminster seems the most advanced, but also to have quite a complexity.

I can't find so many first hand experiences to buckminster on the web, therefore my question to the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: +1, as I hadn't heard of buckminster, so it prompted me to look. At first glance the documentation looks lacking (in basics, e.g. tutorial), so first impression is it'd be a painful adoption process, but I'm interested to see what others post about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We adopted buckminster for our build process in July.

Our set up was to use Ant being run by a CruiseControl server.

We chose it as we have multiple projects living in multiple repositories. We have several RCP products that use different combinations of these projects.

- Managing the checkout (and build) for each of these products *had to be* run off the metadata which we were writing already (manifest files, product files). It was just too easy to get the build and dev metadata out of synch.
- Building bundles and generating a product still is not easy to do by hand.
- New starters need to be up and running quickly. Two+ days to set up a dev environment is not acceptable.

Overall, I found that it is a very powerful tool with poor documentation. There are lots of new concepts, and because it is a framework to plug tools into, some of those names for these concepts can be quite abstract.

However, buckminster absolutely *excelled* at solving the three problems detailed above.

Other additions:

- It can bootstrap itself, as in: it can check itself out, given a minimal core
- It seems to be under active development
- Support via the mailing list is terse, but generally helpful.
- It has a rudimentary scripting language. Very rudimentary.

On the downside (apart from the lack of docs):

- it is still not mature - you find the occasional bugs, and some features which just should be there, but aren't.
- I could not work out how to make the test bundle work
- Testing OSGi products is still non-trivial and not easily made headless.

Overall, I would say that it took a while to bed in, but does an excellent job. I cannot compare it with Ivy or Maven, though Spring's adoption of OSGi may give critical mass in developer mindshare to Maven.

I have answered a [few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=buckminster) concerning buckminster, for help when you start.

Comment: For now we decided to go with maven2, hopefully that one day in the near future tycho will help us with the eclipse/osgi stuff. But still some problems which are addressed by buckminster are still open. But for our liking buckminster is not ready enough (especially on the documentation side).

Comment: @Mauli How are your expirience with Tycho now?

Comment: The BuckyBook (286 pages) now provides great Documentation.
It is available at http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/ under "Documentation"

Answer (score 0):

We use buckminster running via Jenkins to build a KNIME (eclipse) update site with multiple plugins / features hosted in multiple repositories.  Initial decision was because that it how the [KNIME community contributions](https://www.knime.com/community) are built.  There is a learning curve, but once it is running.  A lot of our initial setup process was based on the instructions at [Developing plugins - continuous integration with Jenkins](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Continous_Integration_with_Jenkins)